# Infer type of object based on object structure in typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to let Typescript infer the type of an object based on its shape.
Let's assume we have the following type definitions:

```js
type Base = {
  id: string;
  attributes: any;
}

type ShapeOne = Base & {
  id: "one";
  attributes: {
    amount: 1 | 2 | 3;
  }
}

type ShapeTwo = Base & {
  id: "two";
  attributes: {
    size: "S" | "M" | "L";
  }
}
```

And an object that matches `ShapeOne`:

```js
const shape = {
  id: "one",
  attributes: {
    amount: 1,
  }
}
```

now I want that Typescript can extract/infer the correct type based on the shape of my Object:

```
type t = ShapeType<typeof shape>; // ShapeOne
```

From reading the documentation this should be possible with nested conditional types, but unfortunately I don't know where to look any further on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conventionally, you should be using `interface`s for such object structures instead of `type` aliases:

```
interface Base {
  id: string;
  attributes: any;
}

interface ShapeOne extends Base {
  id: "one";
  attributes: {
    amount: 1 | 2 | 3;
  }
}

interface ShapeTwo extends Base {
  id: "two";
  attributes: {
    size: "S" | "M" | "L";
  }
}
```

It's not *necessary* to do this, but if you don't then your eventual result might display as the definition of `ShapeOne` without showing the name "`ShapeOne`" anywhere.  Also, since (for example) `{id: "two"; attributes: { size: "S" | "M" | "L"; }}` is already a subtype of `Base`, there's no real reason to use an intersection.  It just clutters things up.

---

In any case, you'll want to come up with an actual [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#discriminating-unions) type, since it will be useful here:

```
type Shape = ShapeOne | ShapeTwo;
```

---

After that we need to change how you define `shape`.  In your case, the compiler will infer its type as

```
/* const shape: {
    id: string;
    attributes: {
        amount: number;
    };
} */
```

It happens that such a type will be seen as assignable to `ShapeOne`, but somewhat fortuitously.  The compiler has forgotten that `shape.id` is the [literal string type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/literal-types.html#string-literal-types) `"one"`.  It has widened it all the way to `string`.  If you ever have a `ShapeThree` that looks like `{id: "three"; attributes: {amount: 4 | 5 | 6;}}`, the compiler would think that `shape` as assignable to maybe `ShapeOne` or `ShapeThree`.

So you need to narrow `shape`.  You can, if you want, annotate it as `Shape`:

```
const shape: Shape = {
  id: "one",
  attributes: {
    amount: 1,
  }
}
```

The compiler will automatically narrow the apparent type of `shape` to `ShapeOne` by [control flow analysis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/8010):

```
type t0 = typeof shape; // ShapeOne
```

and there's nothing you need to do with `ShapeType<>` at all.

---

Or, if you don't want to annotate `shape` as the union, you still need to have a narrower type, possibly via a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions):

```
const shapeNarrow = {
  id: "one",
  attributes: {
    amount: 1,
  }
} as const;

/* const shapeNarrow: {
    readonly id: "one";
    readonly attributes: {
        readonly amount: 1;
    };
} */
```

Notice how the type of `shapeNarrow` is now a *subtype* of `ShapeOne`: it is more specific.  You can then finally write a nested [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) to pull out the right member(s) of a union:

```
type ExtractSubtype<T, U> = T extends any ? U extends T ? T : never : never; 
type t = ExtractSubtype<Shape, typeof shapeNarrow>; 
// type t = ShapeOne
```

So you can write `ShapeType<>` like this:

```
type ShapeType<U> = ExtractSubtype<Shape, U>;
type tGood = ShapeType<typeof shapeNarrow>; // ShapeOne ☺
```

Yay!

Note that distributive conditional types only work on bare type parameters, so you *can't* refactor to:

```
type ShapeTypeBad<U> = Shape extends any ? U extends Shape ? Shape : never : never;
type tBad = ShapeTypeBad<typeof shapeNarrow> // ShapeOne | ShapeTwo
```

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#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-fd6c4da8vRAfX6BB4WZ9-MGgVzQeDCAQRcgAKI6KCIMCyTjsEUAHkyVOQAFUAHzazL5HQQPQGfhJgD89dbhQMLd7LYoGmW0GQo5W-1zUJQzoRheoJbLFbnlaJtZFYpdEDdGuyDeEMrzC9lag0ELn58yc-QJErje1RP77aKXeQvbrr4758-f6nccoEnL5pygYRT3vZ9YVvFR70rbdxXxDJ901JsZSJZEIiJDFkEAXg3AHw9q9oRw9cn0XIsV3LKtN3rI9Zz5ABxSxLBIaCMlgiAELnHdkNdNUDyPaV5kwjRkEALjIgA)